# What is the right way to detect keystrokes within an iframe from the parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a web page which embeds content into an iframe. For the following scenarios, I need to know if there are ways to access key strokes which are entered inside the iframes without having to essentially modify the iframed  content.

1. Parent page is www.testpage.com/framedwidgets.html and the framed content is www.testpage.com/widget1.html.

Widget 1 has normal text input fields and no password fields. Both the widget and the parent are of same origin. Is there a way to detect keystrokes inside the input field in the iframe from a javascript running in the context of parent page? What is the ideal method to retrieve keystrokes?

2. Parent page is www.testpage.com/framedwidgets.html and the framed content is www.anotherpage.com/widget2.html.

Widget 2 is loaded cross-domain. Its content similar to widget 1. Is there a way to retrieve keystrokes within the iframe from a javascript running in the context of parent page?

Comment: Well, that wouldn't be terribly secure, now would it? Imagine someone getting wellsfarge.com and putting wellsfargo.com in a frame and logging everyone's password!

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Agree, that's why pages have to set X-Frame Options if they don't want to be framed by an untrusted third-party. But my question is purely on the javascript capability to access keystrokes inside an iframe.

Comment: Well, you can't, for security reasons. See [the MDN article on the same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) The other domain would essentially have to broadcast the keystrokes it receives (via `postMessage`).

Comment: Heretic Monkey, I don't think this has anything to do with SOP. In the first scenario at the very least. Both the content in frame as well as parent are from the same origin. I do take your point on something inside the iframe broadcasting events to a listener outside. However, I am looking for inputs on alternate ways to achieve it. An example would be IE 5 & 6 bugs which allowed Cross Frame Scripting. However I wanted to be certain that this is possible only if there is a bug which allows that and no JavaScript technique can be leveraged to perform this.

Comment: Your second bullet seems to indicate you are asking about cross-origin API access. If that's not the case, I suggest [edit]ing it to make that clearer.  You can detect keystrokes in an iframe by descending into the iframe's context from the parent via `iframe.contentWindow`, which gets you to the same relative place as `window` gets you in a normal browser context. But again, that's only in same-origin situations.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Appreciate the help. Your comment answers both the questions i had.